# Excel .Find, result of function VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to use `.Find` in VB 2010 in order to find a result of a function.

This is my code:

```
firstFind = xlWorkSheet.Range("E10", "CM10").Find(searchDate, ,     Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, False)
```

I have tried both `xlValues` and `xlFormulas`.

The excel function is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
=G9+7
```

The result is a date, 19-Jul, and that's what I want to be able to search for.

BR
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem without using `.find`

```
Const FOUND As Integer = 1, NOT_FOUND = 0
Dim worksheetNr As Integer = 0, columnNr As Integer, dateFound As Integer = NOT_FOUND

While worksheetNr < xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count And dateFound = NOT_FOUND

    Try
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(worksheetNr)
        xlWorkSheet.Activate()
        columnNr = 7
        While dateFound = NOT_FOUND And (columnNr < 100)
            If (xlWorkSheet.Cells(10, columnNr).Value.Equals(searchDate)) Then
                dateFound = FOUND
            Else
                columnNr += 1
            End If

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write("")
    End Try

End While
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first.  Excel sees dates as integers, so the 19-Jul is actually a number (set the cell with =G9+7 to be general)
For example the date July 19, 2012 = 41109.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you loop through the columns instead of using the find function?
Something like this may be more efficient or easier to customize going forward:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim iColumnSearch As Long
    Dim dtSearchDate As Date
    Dim rngFoundInCell As Range

    dtSearchDate = "7/16/2012"

    '- loop through columns E to CM (Column #'s 5 to 91)
    For iColumnSearch = 5 To 91
        If Cells(10, iColumnSearch).Value = dtSearchDate Then

            Set rngFoundInCell = Cells(10, iColumnSearch)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next iColumnSearch

    If Not rngFoundInCell Is Nothing Then '-if was found
        MsgBox "Found in cell: " & rngFoundInCell.Parent.Name & "!" & rngFoundInCell.Address(External:=False)
    End If


    Set rngFoundInCell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Update:

Note the above code was searching for the date '7/16/2012' specifically because I didn't see where your search string was located. You might could replace that line with:

```
dtSearchDate = Range("G9").value + 7
```